# A Difficult Haskell List

Tags: haskell

I have a question about lists in Haskell.

There is a integer list which consists of different values.
How can I  write a function will calculate all the sub-lists which will consist of **n** elements and **t** total. More clearly,

```
fList [1..5] 5 12
Output: [[1,1,1,4,5], [1,1,2,3,5], [1,1,2,4,4], ... , [2,2,2,3,3]]
```

(Each list consists of 5 elements, and sum of the list is allways 12.)

```
or
fList [2,3,4,6] 7 22
[[2,2,2,2,2,6,6], [2,2,2,2,4,4,6], ..., [3,3,3,3,3,3,4]]
```

(Each list consists of 7 elements, and sum of the list is allways 22.) etc...

`fList :: [Integer] -> Int -> Integer -> [[Integer]]`

*(Source list's elements may be repeated in the destination list.)*

I have no idea how to do it? Can anybody help?

Comment: For some `t`, `n`, compute the problem for every `x` in the given list of size `n-1` and total `t-x` and prepend `x` to that.

Comment: Hint: `sequence $ replicate 5 [1..5]`

Comment: Breaking down the problem : you want to enumerate all the combinations of `n` elements which belongs to the set, and then filter those whose sum is `t`.

Comment: But this might not be the most efficient way of doing it. And you'll get duplicates, if your enumeration is order sensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about

```
filter ((12==).sum) $ mapM (const [1..5]) [1..5]
```

(or

```
filter ((22==).sum) $ mapM (const [2..6]) [1..7]
```

EDITED:

I wish you have tried solve your problem, anyway, here's a possible trivial (using basic Haskell) solution (please, try understand)

```
fList :: [Integer] -> Int -> Integer -> [[Integer]]
fList  _ 0 0 = [[]] -- Empty list with 0 elements sum 0
fList  _ 0 _ = []   -- No list exists with 0 elements with sum != 0
fList [] _ _ = []   -- With no elements, must be n == 0
fList (x:xs) n toSum =
   concat [ map ((take z $ repeat x)++)                             -- add x z times
                (fList xs (n - z) (toSum - fromIntegral z * x))     -- reducing the problem size
          | z <- reverse [0..min n (fromInteger (toSum `div` x))]   -- using x, z=0,1,... times
          ]
```

Comment: Note that this will contain lists with the same elements, but with another order. That can be fixed easily with `nub . sort . map sort`.

Comment: `nub . sort . map sort` is an overkill in this context.

Comment: @Nicolas: So is going through all `k^n` possible combinations, which is basically what josejuan's answer is about.

Comment: I meant that you can filter redundancy in a cleverer way.

Comment: @josejuan I have tried, but it was a bit difficult for me. Thank you very much for your solution.

Comment: @sasas next time, try to explain your tries (also wrong tries), where you are stuck, ...

Answer (score 3):

This looks like homework.

`fList` produces a list of solutions. This means that you can produce some solutions, and append a list of solutions produced by `fList` with different arguments.

Suppose `fList` uses up `1`. Now you have a shorter list to produce, and a smaller sum to compute. You can use `fList` to produce solutions for that problem, and append `1` to the head.

(then also suppose `fList` doesn't use any `1` - what do you need to do next?)